# PhoneGap WindowsPhone 8 Facebook Connect with InAppBrowser

Tags: facebook, cordova, windows-phone, phonegap-plugins

Using the PhoneGap plugin phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser  https://github.com/caiovaccaro/phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser

It fails after entering the Facebook login details. A blank screen with error message  "We are having trouble displaying this page." appears.

My conjecture is that this is due to trying to call show() on the InAppBrowser which is not supported in Windows Phone.

The code from the plugin that is suspected is line 171 of the plugin in the login method:

```
 faceView.addEventListener('loadstop', function(){
    faceView.show();        
    });
```

This approach works fine on iOS and Android.

Was someone able to use the plugin on Windows Phone? Or can you point me to some useful plugin to do Facebook login in PhoneGap on Windows Phone?

Would appreciate any insight.

**After Further Tests**

Able to resolve.

It works on Windows Phone in the current version. 
What happened is that when you install the InAppBrowser plugin on a Mac and you then want to use it in Windows Phone it does not work properly. It happened to me also for the Device Motion plugin. 
You are able to make the call in the JavaScript but nothing happens on the native level. 
I had to create two branches in Git. One for Android and iOS and another for Windows Phone. Then, add the plugin separately in each. By the way if you add the plugin on Windows, phone gap build had compilation errors for iOS later on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you [this API sample-facebook-api](https://github.com/Icenium/sample-facebook-api) works fine, go to login facebook and accept the permissions... but when its come back to app, this broke... if you can solve this please say me how you do...

Ok! i finally solved creating a FB login native and send it to webview!